# Count the number of values in a nested list that are greater and less than certain values

Tags: list, haskell, nested, runtime-error, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm working on a function for a homework problem that counts the number of values in a list for which the values are greater than `v1` and less than `v2`. I've put something together that works but only in a specific case. When I try something else I get the error of

> *** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function countInRange

This function is supposed to call on `getInRange`. `getInRange` just returns values from a list that are greater than `v1` and less than `v2`. Here is what it looks like.

```
rangeHelper v1 v2 x | x > v1 && x < v2 = True
                    | otherwise = False

getInRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
getInRange v1 v2 iL = filter(rangeHelper v1 v2) iL

count iL = sum (map (const 1) iL)

countInRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [[a]] -> Int
countInRange v1 v2 [iL] = count ((getInRange v1 v2) iL)
```

If I were to call

```
countInRange 3 10 [[4,5,6]]         -- works, prints 3
countInRange 3 10 [[1,2], [4,5,6]]  -- error: non exhaustive patterns
```

Comment: `countInRange v1 v2 [iL]` should be `countInRange v1 v2 iL` (no square brackets, your version only applies to a singleton list, whose member is itself a list of numbers). Unless you really want it to accept a list of lists, but that (even with the input that "works") looks quite strange to me.

Comment: Well the requirement is that I need to pass in two values and a nested list because I need to be able to work on the lists within the list.

Comment: (Minor style point: `rangeHelper v1 v2 x = x > v1 && x < v2` is simpler. Don't check if a boolean value is true/false only to return the exact same value.)

Comment: I don't completely understand your goal. What is the expected result of `countInRange 3 10 [[1,2],[3,40]]`? Three? So, in general `countInRange 3 10 [[a,b],[c,d]]` must be the same as `countInRange 3 10 [[a,b,c,d]]`? If so, consider `concat`enating the list of lists into a single list before counting.

Comment: The goal would be to print the value of 3 when I call countInRange 3 10 [[1,2], [4,5,6]] because 4,5,6 are the only values that are greater 3 and less than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `countInRange` function only expects a list that contains one list. When you write `countInRange v1 v2 [iL]` you only define it to match pattern when your list contains single element called `iL`. You can also use `count  = length`

You can fix this issue by defining it like this:

```
countInRange v1 v2 xs  = sum (map (length.filter (rangeHelper v1 v2)) xs)
-- or
countInRange v1 v2     = sum.map (length.filter (rangeHelper v1 v2))
```

Comment: Instead of filtering & counting each list, and then summing the counts, I think it's simpler to concatenate, filter, and then count, as in `length . filter (rangeHelper v1 v2) . concat`.

Comment: @chi sure, that would be a better solution, I was just trying to change as little as possible in the existing solution

Answer (score 3):

If we were to simplify your function even to just

```
countInRange v1 v2 [ iL ]  =  0
```

we would still observe the same behavior:

```
countInRange 3 10 [ [4,5,6]        ]   -- returns 0
countInRange 3 10 [ [1,2], [4,5,6] ]   -- ***Error: Non-exhaustive patterns
```

Can you see the problem, here?

Comment: The answer is much better with your edit. StackOverflow at its best (imho). And thanks to you.

Comment: just a little copy editing, is all. :) the main idea is yours. and you're welcome. this reminds me of [tag:failure-slice]: to see the problem clearer, minimize the code as much as possible while it still exhibits the same problematic behaviour.

Comment: I call it minimization or test case generation and it is my favorite/go-to debugging technique.